# Error in SQL syntax - need to remove database

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I'm trying to setup a music server with a service called Ampache (which is basically a MySQL Apache server) but I've obviously done something wrong with the database when setting it up as I keep getting this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES
    -> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW DATABASES' at line 2
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES SHOW DATABASES
    -> SHOW SCHEMA
    -> SHOW SCHEMA;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW DATABASES
SHOW SCHEMA
SHOW SCHEMA' at line 1
```

So, how can I delete all databases and users in order to start again?

Comment: At first sight it appears that you're issuing the command twice: `SHOW DATABASES SHOW DATABASES` - did you try just `SHOW DATABASES;`?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski Yeah the first command didn't work as I didn't end it with the semi-colon ending